# SOAP Parameters are not displayed while creating BIRT DataSet for the Webservice DataSoucre

Tags: soap, birt

I want to develop the BIRT Report by using the Webservice.

I have created a simple webservice which contains only one operation (method). It has few simple input parameters. I have created a DataSource by selecting the “Webservices DataSource” and given the WSDL URL.

I am trying to create DataSet for the WebService DataSource. After the selecting the WSDL Operation, the SOAP parameters are not shown in the DataSet Wizard.
This webservice is the secured webservice.
How to resolve it?